# ltspice, plot Vpp

Tags: ltspice

Maybe this is extremely trivial.

I have a transient analysis over a buck regulator and can't figure out how to plot Vpp. I just want to sweep some capacitors and see the ripple.

In PSpice you can add expression directly to plot (like V*sqrt(2)), I can't figure out how to do this in LtSpice. If I click the name of the plot, I can enter some expression but always gave me error such as "undefined symbol" Vpp(noo4)

I also added a .measure directive in schematic but nothing happens to the plot

```
.meas TRAN x PP v(n004)
```

What I miss?
Thank you.

My buck's output
[image]

Comment: Look in the log! That's where the result appears.

Answer (score 3):

vpp measurement in ltspice is a single value over the whole plot (or a section thereof, check `.meas` parameters). Look in the error log (weird place, I know)

For sweeping multiple values of a single component, use the `.step param` facility, and then you can right click in the error log and plot the `.meas` values vs. component values.

Comment: Not sure if this is ok! the total Vpp will include ramping from zero, isn't it? please see attached picture, this is actual buck output and I need to plot Vpp in certain region (skip startup) to see what is it. A real scope on my bench will compute this on fly over zoomed region only...

Comment: @user1734108: the .meas command includes x axis ranges for the measurement, just let it start far enough after the ramp up phase

Answer (score 1):

Your .meas command will put results in the error log, found in View-->SPICE Error Log. Alternatively you can use the keyboard shortcut 'Ctrl+L'.

[image]